# Rename file to include modified date in file name

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that will copy JPG files from my digital camera to my hard drive. But, I'd also like it to include the file's date in the name.

For example:  A picture taken on 1/23/11 is named P1230001.JPG would be renamed P1230001_20110123.JPG.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.digicamsoft.com/softnamexif.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a helper batch file that will do what you want.  It takes one parameter the file to rename and renames the file with the date appended.  Hope this helps.

```
@echo off
setlocal

if "%1"=="" goto USAGE
set file_name=%1
set name=%~n1
set ext=%~x1

dir %file_name% | findstr /i %file_name% > y.tmp

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (y.tmp) do (
set line=%%i
)

del y.tmp

set month=%line:~0,2%
set day=%line:~3,2%
set year=%line:~6,4%

ren %file_name% %name%_%year%%month%%day%%ext%

goto EOF

:USAGE

echo %0 file_name

:EOF
endlocal
```